# Grazing tile question

Tags: untagged

In Silk the primary way to get points is by grazing you silkworms.

The rules for the grazing action are;

> Grazing
> This action allows a player to earn Silk Points.
> .
> Depending on the number of silkworms and the tile on which they are feeding, the player will earn points and update the scoreboard accordingly.
> .
> A player can carry out the Grazing action on any tile where he has at least one silkworm. To do so he must follow these steps:
> • Bump all the silkworms that are on that tile, distributing them (together or separately) to one or more adjacent tiles (following the normal movement rules). If it is not possible to bump all of the silkworms, this action cannot be performed on that tile. Remember: if the tile being grazed on is at the edge of the game area, the player can bump the silkworms out of the area, which means they are lost in the mountains (and returned to their owner’s reserve). Any silkworms bumped onto a tile occupied by the ookami are immediately captured and are placed in the
> ookami’s den.
> • Turn over the tile that was grazed, turning it into a barren tile (valued 0 silk points).
> • The number of Silk Points the player receives is found by multiplying the number of silkworms he has on that tile by the value of the tile on which they are feeding. If there are also silkworms
> of another color on the tile, their owners do not get any points. Note: It is possible to graze on a barren tile, but in that case the silkworms are just bumped around and no one obtains any points as a result of the action.

The tense in the last section of the rules is confusing me. It feels like the point should come from the turned over time where the silk worms were grazing when you stated the action. But the use of 'has' and 'are' instead of had and were could be read to mean the destination tiles of the bumped silkworms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having played the game, the note in the end seems clear to me:

> Note: It is possible to graze on a barren tile, but in that case the
> silkworms are just bumped around and no one obtains any points as a
> result of the action.

If you would collect the points from the destination tile, it should not matter what the state of the tile is where you performed the action. So the order is:

Do action (grazing) -> calculate points -> move worms -> turn tile

Comment: I was just coming back after finding a publisher explainer video... Anyway you're spot on.